# Submit binary data via Prototype Ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs, filereader

I'm using Prototype to submit a POST request, and the postdata contains a number of fields, one of which is binary data from a file (in this case an Excel spreadsheet the user has selected for upload.)

I am using the HTML5 FileReader interface to get the contents of the file via `FileReader.readAsBinaryString()` which works well.  If I use `charCodeAt()` to print various characters in the string then they come out with the expected values.

However once I put this string data in an object (along with the other form fields) and pass it as the `parameters` option to Prototype's `Ajax.Request()`, the data arrives corrupted.  Certain character values like `0x82` are replaced with `0xC2 0x82`, `0xAC` is replaced with `0xC2 0xAC`, and so on.

I tried using `window.atob()` to base64 encode the string, but this fails with `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character`, so clearly there is some kind of processing going on which I need to avoid.

Does anyone know how to pass binary data through Prototype's `Ajax.Request()` while also including additional form fields in the same request?

Answer (score 1):

To do ajax file upload you should really use a FormData object

```
var data = new FormData();
//var data = new FormData(someForm); if all your fields is in an html form
// add fields to form
data.append('fieldname',fieldvalue);
data.append('filefieldname',fileobject);
//etc

new Ajax.Request(url, {
    contentType: null,
    method: 'post',
    postBody: data,
    onSuccess: successFunction
})
```

With this method the server will see the request like if it was sent by a form with attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: I tried this, sending it to a PHP script, and I had to also set `contentType: 'multipart/form-data'`.  However then it comes up with the PHP error `Missing boundary in multipart/form-data`, so I guess you can't set the `postBody` to be the `FormData` object?

Comment: Do not set contentType to `multipart/form-data` set it to null as shown in my answer.

Comment: Setting `contentType: null` per your answer (no quotes or anything) causes the browser to submit the HTTP request with `Content-Type: null; charset=UTF-8`.  It looks like the MIME boundary needs to be specified in the HTTP `Content-Type` header in order for the `multipart/form-type` data to work correctly, but I cannot see how this should be done.

Comment: Okay, this doesn't work... my bad.  There doesn't seem like there is a way to prevent prototype from setting the content type, the closest thing I saw was when you set `contentType: '',encoding: '',` but that still gives a rouge comma at the beginning of the header.

Comment: Your answer pushed me in the right direction though.  Turns out [there's an open bug with a fix](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/pull/314) that when applied, makes your answer work.  Here's hoping they will include that fix in the next Prototype release!

Answer (score 0):

Doing this requires magic and pixie dust. (well not really)

firstly you would need to put the form fields values as URL parameters instead of POST and then  override the post body with the file contents. For example

```
new Ajax.Request('/url.php?rawupload=1&id='+$F('id')+'&label='+label,
    {
        'method':'post',
        'postBody':fileobject,
        'onSuccess':function() { alert('success'); }
    });
```

`fileobject` is the HTML5 file object retrieved from the file upload input element

Yes its not the most elegant solution if you have lots of form fields. You can also use `Hash#toQueryString` if you do have lots of form fields to build your query string instead of doing them by hand

http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Hash/prototype/toQueryString/